# Rotated video with ffmpeg doesn't play in flowplayer in IE9

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, internet-explorer-9, flowplayer

I have a script that rotates videos 90 degrees and then the videos are displayed on a web page using [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) (HTML5 version, not Flash). After the video is rotated once it does not play in IE9 but plays without any other problems in Chrome and Firefox.
The error message is: Video file not found.

I've looked in IE9's developer tools console, in the network tab and the browser streams the whole video.

The following is the ffmpeg command I use to rotate and convert the video:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -y -r 30 -b 4M -vf 'transpose=1,scale=800:trunc(ow/a/2)*2' -ar 48000 -vcodec libx264 -profile baseline -preset slow -level 2.2 output.mp4`

This is the input file which I used: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37994/local%20capture.mov

This is the output video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37994/local%20capture%20rotated.mp4

The input video from above is a screen capture made using QuickTime on Mac OS.

This also happened for this video: http://mirrorblender.top-ix.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov
And also this one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37994/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4

This didn't happen for the sample .mov from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1425

If I run the command twice, meaning I rotate the video 90 degrees and then I rotate the output using the same command once more, the problem disappears, but I need to be able to rotate only 90 degrees.

This problem doesn't happen if I put IE9 in IE7 or IE8 compatibility mode.

I was thinking that maybe the problem was how the server serves the video but there's no problem with other videos.

I looked at the metadata with ffmpeg but didn't see anything significant.

I already have `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` in .htaccess.

I can't seem to pin down what's causing this problem.

Edit:

Request in IE9
[image: IE9 request]

Response in IE9
[image: IE9 response]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by applying the wrong scaling to the portrait videos while using transpose and this caused the sample_aspect_ratio of the video to change from 1:1 to something else and it seems that IE9 cannot handle anything different from 1:1.

Instead of

```
scale=FIXED_WIDTH:trunc(ow/a/2)*2
```

I should've used

```
scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:FIXED_HEIGHT
```

This way the sample aspect ratio remains 1:1.

I got help from here: http://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/setup#rotate